# How do I call out the Agent Type for a custom block?

Tags: anylogic

I have a custom block that needs parameter and variable info from the agent passing through it. I would like to design this block for use with different agent types.  How do I create a pulldown of all of the available agent types in the current model like in other built-in blocks? I'm assuming it's a parameter with an internal value, but just not sure of the parameter type, method to pull the agent types, etc. See picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use generic parameters (for the agent type that your custom block is defined within) as outlined in this help section: **AnyLogic Help > Parameters, Variables, Collections > Parameters > Generic Parameters**.

By giving the parametrized type a label of "Agent type:" (instead of the default "Generic parameter:") you can also make it look more as it does in AnyLogic's blocks.

(The main difference is that it's not in an Advanced properties section.)

Just remember to use whatever you named your generic type (e.g., `T`) as the agent type for the blocks (or other code) inside your custom block (for those areas where you need to see it as that type instead of a generic Agent).

This is using [Java generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) under the covers, hence why there is some specific Java syntax such as `T extends Agent` for the type parameter detail (which just means that the generic type T is some subclass (sub-type) of Agent).

Comment: So I've been out of this customization for a while, but I'm getting back into it.  I've reviewed both Anylogic's Help and the Oracle Java generics link supplied above, but am having issues implementing it.  My end goal is here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61684947/how-can-i-use-the-getservicedentity-method-on-a-resource-unit-without-casting)

Answer (score 1):

You use type-casting as below. Note that the "Agent type" setting should stay at the default (and most generic) "Agent"

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. Sometimes I'll insert my block into a flow that has a Cart agent type moving through it. Other times it will be in a flow that has a Person agent type moving through it. Other times, it will be in a PalletJack flow.  How do I create a pulldown that lets the block know what type of agent is flowing through it so I can cast the correct agent type to pull the parameters correctly?

Comment: ah, ok. See my new answer above

Comment: I think he's talking about having his custom blocks include an "Agent type" parameter (as for AnyLogic-provided blocks) so that they can support multiple agent types passing through. (There is no such setting for custom blocks by default and thus no way to out-of-the-box allow, for example, users of the custom block to access a type-specific `agent` in action properties of the block.)